# What's the most efficient way of truncating the names in a first_name and last_name column to 1 character?

Tags: mysql, sql, sanitization, anonymize

What's the most efficient way of truncating the names in a first_name and last_name column to 1 character?

I have a mysql database that I want to hand off to a developer but I want to partially sanitize the data so that the two name records drop down to just initials.

I tried to modify the varchar to 1 character but mysql will not let me truncate the data, it just throws an error. I am working from a dump of the database before I hand it off. I want to obscure the names without making them all the same.

Comment: Do the update in chunks to keep transaction size down. Perhaps 10000 - 100000 rows per update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update tablename set first_name=left(first_name, 1), last_name = left(last_name, 1)
```

But, as Gordon Linoff mentioned, this could be expensive if you have a lot of rows in the table

Comment: I like this answer and it works but I keep getting this error `ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'user_id' cannot be null` But I don't get that at all because we aren't editing the user_id  in the query and the weirdest part is that when I display the records again it executed properly for 1 set of records. have you seen anything like that before?

Comment: To make this even weirder, I ran the query about 20 times and at some point it finished all the rest without complaining. I can't figure out what that's about.

Comment: @Tenthrow No idea why you would have been getting that error

Comment: It looks like something caused by a trigger, but I didn't design this database so I didn't know it was there. Go figure. You're query worked great! Thank you!

Comment: @Tenthrow Yeah, I was actually about to comment that it looked like something that might be caused by a constraint or a trigger

Answer (score 0):

Updating all the rows is rather expensive because of the logging required.  The most efficient way is probably to create a new table:

```
create table for_developer as
    select left(first_name, 1) as first_name, left(last_name, 1) as last_name,
           . . . -- rest of columns
    from t;
```

Comment: Would I be able to replace the original table like that? I need to result to have identical structure to the production database.

Comment: @Tenthrow . . . Just list the rest of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try:

```
Update "you_table"
SET first_name = LEFT(first_name,1), 
last_name = LEFT(last_name,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `like` when creating a new table so you have the same column attribute and definitions as the old table. Be sure to check the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html) on the behavior of `like` when creating tables though, especially if you are concerned about indexing.

```
create table new_table like old_table;

insert into new_table

select left(first_name, 1) as first_name, left(last_name, 1) as last_name, ..-- rest of columns
from old_table;
```